# Unable to locate Attribute with the given name - Spring Data JPA Projections, Hibernate and BaseEntity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am mapping Entities in Hibernate with JPA and Spring Data and when I run application I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [id] on this ManagedType [p.s.t..entity.BaseEntity]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:633) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:175) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
```

I have a superclass BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;

    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return this == that ||
            that instanceof BaseEntity && Objects.equals(uuid, ((BaseEntity) that).uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(uuid);
    }
}
```

Regular class Task, which extends the **BaseClass**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "task")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Task.detail",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("attachments"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("tags")
    }
)
public class Task extends BaseEntity {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Set<Attachment> attachments = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "tags_tasks",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public Task(String title, String description, LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename, String comment) {
        attachments.add(new Attachment(filename, comment));
    }

    public Set<Attachment> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.add(tag);
    }

    public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.remove(tag);
    }
}
```

**TaskView** for JPA query projection:

```
public interface TaskView {
    Long getId();
    String getUuid();
    String getTitle();
    String getDescription();
    LocalDateTime getCreatedAt();
}
```

And JpaRepository interface:

```
interface TasksCrudRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(value = "Task.detail", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Task> findAll();

    List<TaskView> findAllProjectedBy();
}
```

The last method - **findAllProjectedBy()** - in the **TaskCrudRepository** causes the exception pasted at the begnining of this post.

When I remove `getId()` method from `TaskView` it starts, but then I am not able to display the `id` of the `Task` in the projection.

So the question is what I am missing in this whole classes structure?

I am using:

- Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE
- Java 11
- Hibernate Core 5.3.12.FINAL
- JPA 2.2

Comment: Could you please try to correct `BaseEntity.Id` to `BaseEntity.id`.

Comment: Might be a lombok issue. Try with manual created getters and setters. Also consider using https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html instead of your BaseEntity, since it's already provided by Spring.

Comment: @SternK I just find it out myself. FACEPALM. Nevertheless thanks for the correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in `BaseEntity` when defining ID field. Should be camelcase `id` instead of `Id`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return this == that ||
            that instanceof BaseEntity && Objects.equals(uuid, ((BaseEntity) that).uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(uuid);
    }
}
```